# gmail api auth issue - cannot get attachment from the chosen email

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I'm working with node.js v13 with Gmail api.
I have done successfully getting the specific email message and now I'm trying
to get the attachment from that same email.

```
function getRecentEmail(auth) {
// Only get the recent email - 'maxResults' parameter
gmail.users.messages.list({ auth: auth, userId: 'me', maxResults: 1, q: 'subject:pokerrrr' }, function (
    err,
    response
) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        return;
    }

    // Get the message id which we will need to retreive tha actual message next.
    const message_id = response['data']['messages'][0]['id'];

    // Retreive the actual message using the message id
    gmail.users.messages.get({ auth: auth, userId: 'me', id: message_id }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        // const attachment_id = response['data'].payload.parts[1].body.attachmentId;
        const message = response['data'];
        // getAttachments('me', message, auth);
        const parts = message.payload.parts;
        for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            const part = parts[i];
            if (part.filename && part.filename.length > 0) {
                const attachId = part.body.attachmentId;
                gmail.users.messages.attachments.get(
                    {
                        id: attachId,
                        messageId: message.id,
                        userId: 'me',
                    },
                    function (attachment) {

                        // saveAttachmentsToDir(part.filename, part.mimeType, attachment);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}

when I run the code above, the attachment parameter is showing me auth error and I cant understand why.
here is the error:

```js
code:401
config:Object {url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messa…", method: "GET", paramsSerializer: , …}
errors:Array(1) [Object]
message:"Login Required"
response:Object {config: Object, data: Object, headers: Object, …}
stack:"Error: Login Required
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (c:\Users\tomer\Desktop\Mail listener -tomer\Mail listener\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:73:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (c:\Users\tomer\Desktop\Mail listener -tomer\Mail listener\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
__proto__:Error {constructor: }
```

Comment: Hello @TomerZaidler, which scopes are you using? Cheers!

Comment: Hello @ale13, Those are the scopes:   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',

Comment: Hello @TomerZailder, did you add new ones when trying to get the attachment? Moreover, the "401 Login Required" error message you are receiving is due to the fact that the credentials used are not the appropriate ones hence the login cannot be done accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 I am sure that the credentials that I use is the appropriate ones beacuse I am getting data from the email message itself.
I started the project with those scopes, I didn't add anything..

Comment: Hello @TomerZaidler, did you add new scopes when you tried to get the attachment? Because if that's the case, you need to get new a credentials since the old ones will contain the auth for the old scopes. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @ale13 , I didn't add any new scopes when I tried to get the attachment..

Comment: Hello @TomerZaidler, which kind of attachment is the one you are trying to retrieve? Is it a file from a Drive? Cheers!

Comment: Hello @ale13, I'm trying to get am docx file that attached to an email

Comment: Hello @TomerZaidler, can you confirm that the access token is still valid and it hasn't expired? Cheers!

Comment: Hello @ale13 , yes I can confirm that the access token is still valid because when I'm able to fetch the email but not the attachments

Comment: Hello @TomerZaidler, do you have access to that specific attachment? Can you try to see if this occurs when retrieving another attachment? Cheers!